# Combine list with dataframe and extend the multi-values cells into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming I have the following input:

```
table = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,0,0],'b':[1,1,1,3,],'c':[2,2,5,4],'d':[3,6,6,6]},dtype='float64')

list = [[55,66],
        [77]]

#output of the table
         a    b    c    d
    0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
    1  0.0  1.0  2.0  6.0
    2  0.0  1.0  5.0  6.0
    3  0.0  3.0  4.0  6.0
```

I want to combine `list` with `table` so **the final shape** would be like:

```
     a    b    c    d  ID_0   ID_1
0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  55.0   66.0
1  0.0  1.0  2.0  6.0  77.0    NaN
2  0.0  1.0  5.0  6.0   NaN    NaN
3  0.0  3.0  4.0  6.0   NaN    NaN
```

I found a way but it looks a bit long and might be a shorter way to do it.

*Step1:*

```
x = pd.Series(list, name ="ID")
new = pd.concat([table, x], axis=1)

# output
     a    b    c    d      ID
0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  [5, 6]
1  0.0  1.0  2.0  6.0    [77]
2  0.0  1.0  5.0  6.0     NaN
3  0.0  3.0  4.0  6.0     NaN
```

*step2:*

```
ID = new['ID'].apply(pd.Series)
ID = ID.rename(columns = lambda x : 'ID_' + str(x))
new_x = pd.concat([new[:], ID[:]], axis=1)

# output
     a    b    c    d      ID  ID_0  ID_1
0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  [5, 6]   5.0   6.0
1  0.0  1.0  2.0  6.0    [77]  77.0   NaN
2  0.0  1.0  5.0  6.0     NaN   NaN   NaN
3  0.0  3.0  4.0  6.0     NaN   NaN   NaN
```

*step3:*

```
new_x = new_x.drop(columns=['ID'], axis = 1)
```

Any shorter way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a default index on `table` (as shown in the question), we can simply create a DataFrame (either [from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) or with the [constructor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)) and [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to `table` and allow the indexes to align. ([add_prefix](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) is an easy way to add the 'ID_' prefix to the default numeric columns)

```
new_df = table.join(
    pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst).add_prefix('ID_')
)
```

`new_df`:

```
     a    b    c    d  ID_0  ID_1
0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  55.0  66.0
1  0.0  1.0  2.0  6.0  77.0   NaN
2  0.0  1.0  5.0  6.0   NaN   NaN
3  0.0  3.0  4.0  6.0   NaN   NaN
```

---

Working with 2 DataFrames is generally easier than a DataFrame and a list. Here is what [from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) does to `lst`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst)

    0     1
0  55  66.0
1  77   NaN
```

Index (rows) 0 and 1 will now align with the corresponding index values in `table` (0 and 1 respectively).

[add_prefix](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) fixes the column names before joining:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst).add_prefix('ID_')

   ID_0  ID_1
0    55  66.0
1    77   NaN
```

---

Setup and imports:

```
import pandas as pd  # v1.4.4

table = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    'b': [1, 1, 1, 3, ],
    'c': [2, 2, 5, 4],
    'd': [3, 6, 6, 6]
}, dtype='float64')

lst = [[55, 66],
       [77]]
```